# Extracted data and XSS

Tags: php, entities

I am currently extracting data from a RSS feed (XML). An example would be:

```
Bob&#39;s dog
```

Now I have a problem: I would like to protect myself against XSS due to the data coming from a foreign source. Therefore, I go ahead and escape the data, result:

```
Bob&amp;#39;s dog
```

Now when I'm trying to print the data I extracted, it prints:

```
Bob&#39;s dog
```

... instead of ...

```
Bob's dog
```

Question: How can I protect myself against XSS but still print the data by avoiding double-entities?

Comment: Using a regular expression to filter the input can prevent an XSS attack. You only accecpt alpha-numbericals, whitespaces and percent-encoded symbols input.
An example of such a regexp could be "([A-Za-z0-9\\s]+)|(&#\\d{1,3};)".
You could then negate the regexp and remove the matches; E.g. ([^A-Za-z0-9\\s]+)|([^(&#\\d{1,3};)])

Comment: First decode the string you got and after that use `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: That seems radical. Isn't there a possibility to decode entities first and then encode them again alongside the other special characters?

Comment: Yes you can and should

Comment: Now that works but what if I have 'Bob&amp;#39;s dog' already and would like to print that nicely? Double decode and then encode? Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh, got it. I have to set ENT_QUOTES as flag in htmlspecialchars_decode() due to &#39; being a single-quote. Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1):

First you want to decode the string using either [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). And after that re-encode the string to prevent XSS using:

```
htmlspecialchars($theString, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // or whatever encoding
```

Although the data already looks like it is encoded we re-encode it either way, because the 3rd party at some point can decide at some point to start using raw data instead.

This way you would still be protected.